# Como copiar una tabla de una BD de un Servidor a otra BD de otro Servidor - SQL SERVER 2016

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, consola

Tengo que hacer un programa de consola en C# el cual me ayude a copiar una tabla con todos sus registros de un servidor y vaciarlos a otra tabla de otro servidor, en este caso el servidor origen tengo permisos de lectura y en el servidor destino de escritura por lo que no va haber problema, por eso quisiera pedir su ayuda para saber como realizar esto ya que no tengo muchos conocimientos haciendo este tipo de cosas y no tengo idea de como hacerlo... he visto que se puede hacer generando un script dando clic derecho sobre la base de datos- tareas- generar script pero esto no me serviria ya que haciendolo con un programa de consola puedo hacer tareas programadas para que la informacion se mantenga actualizada a la original. Tambien se que puedo evitar hacer el programa con un link server pero esta no es una opcion por tiempo de espera para que me lo generen.

Mil gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo buscas-> Copiar datos de una tabla de un servidor 1 a una tabla en el servidor 2, con un programa de consola con c# ¿me equivoco?

Comment: En caso de ser así primero tienes que hacer tres fases. Primero conseguir leer los datos con un select.  segundo guardarlos temporalmente en una classe, y finalmente hacer el insert o update al servidor 2 [link de como hacer la conexion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)

Comment: Has probado usar SSIS? Puedes generar el paquete con la opción de importar/exportar datos y guardarlo para llamarlo cuando necesites desde la consola.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para copiar una tabla con todos sus registros de un servidor a otro en C#, puedes utilizar la librería System.Data.SqlClient para conectarte a las bases de datos y ejecutar las consultas necesarias.
Ejemplo básico de cómo podrías hacerlo:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string connectionString1 = "Data Source=server1;Initial Catalog=mydb;User ID=myuser;Password=mypassword"; // conexión al servidor origen
        string connectionString2 = "Data Source=server2;Initial Catalog=mydb;User ID=myuser;Password=mypassword"; // conexión al servidor destino
        string tableName = "mytable"; // nombre de la tabla que se va a copiar

        try {
            // conectar al servidor origen
            using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString1)) {
                connection1.Open();

                // leer todos los registros de la tabla
                string sql = $"SELECT * FROM {tableName}";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection1)) {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
                        // conectar al servidor destino
                        using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString2)) {
                            connection2.Open();

                            // copiar cada registro a la tabla destino
                            while (reader.Read()) {
                                sql = $"INSERT INTO {tableName} VALUES (";
                                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++) {
                                    if (i > 0) {
                                        sql += ",";
                                    }
                                    object value = reader.GetValue(i);
                                    if (value == null || value == DBNull.Value) {
                                        sql += "NULL";
                                    } else if (value is string) {
                                        sql += $"'{value}'";
                                    } else {
                                        sql += value.ToString();
                                    }
                                }
                                sql += ")";
                                using (SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(sql, connection2)) {
                                    command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Tabla copiada correctamente.");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error al copiar tabla: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

En este ejemplo, se definen dos cadenas de conexión connectionString1 y connectionString2 para conectarse al servidor origen y destino, respectivamente. Luego, se utiliza un objeto SqlConnection para conectarse a la base de datos en cada servidor, y se ejecuta una consulta SQL para leer todos los registros de la tabla que se va a copiar.

Luego, se utiliza un segundo objeto SqlConnection para conectarse al servidor destino, y se utiliza un objeto SqlDataReader para leer cada registro de la tabla origen. Para cada registro, se construye una consulta SQL para insertarlo en la tabla destino utilizando el método ExecuteNonQuery de un objeto SqlCommand.

Ten en cuenta que este es un ejemplo básico y que puede ser necesario ajustarlo para tu caso particular. Por ejemplo, puedes necesitar incluir filtros en la consulta SELECT para leer solo los registros que te interesan, o puedes necesitar ajustar el manejo de tipos de datos y valores NULL.

Comment: Te lo agradezco amigo, intentare realizarlo así y ver si me funciona

Comment: De nada! espero que te funcione como lo esperas!!

Comment: Hola amigo, intente probar el codigo reciente ya que antes tuve problemas con mis cadenas de conexion pero ya las resolvi y al ejecutar tu codigo me marca este error Incorrect syntax near '5'  Sabes porque motivo es este error?

Comment: puedes hacer un Console.WriteLine(sql) antes de ejecutar "ExecuteNonQuery();  o simplemente poner un break y ver que es lo que tiene la variable sql. Eso mismo se puede ejecutar directamente con el management studio y ver que puede ser que este mal. Si no te das cuenta pegalo en un comentario y veo de poder ayudarte.